# In which scripture does Hanuman fight with Balarama?

Tags: hanuman, balarama

I remember watching on TV Hanuman eating some fruits from an orchard and Balarama challenges him not knowing that he was Hanuman.

Comment: Are you sure it Is Balarama or Bhima? Which TV show is it? There is a fight between Bhima and Hanuman though.

Comment: Very much sure - Krishna knows what is going on but lets Balarama be fooled.  I don't remember the name of the show.